# LaTeX in gtsummary row labels

Tags: r, gtsummary

How does one add LaTeX in gtsummary row labels. I thought this would work:

```
library(gtsummary)
mtcars %>%
  tbl_summary(
    by = cyl,
    label = mpg ~ "$\sigma_{Gallon}$",
  )
```

But it doesn't. Instead it gives `Error: '\s' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""$\s"`

Comment: Why not just `$sigma`. In R a single backslash is an escape and the parser has no assigned meaning for an escaped-s. I’m not a skilled user of the “gt” suite but I suspect the `\s` is hitting the R parser first.

Comment: I tried both \\ and the solution you just suggested. Doesn't work. In using R Markdown I use `$...$` to create an inline latex environment so I thought maybe this would work here too.

Comment: If you are using Markdown, then why didn't you include full code to run it that way? My point was that you had an escape character in front of a lowercase-s in code that was going to be handled by the R interpreter.. If you are using a preprocessor than escape characters might be interpreted differently.